# Is viewstate bad for SEO?

Tags: asp.net, seo

I am new to asp.net and have got some concerns about the bloated viewstate on a small site I'll be maintaining.

Since I actually don't want to learn asp.net (mvc looks interesting though), my question is if I should care about this potential issue or just wait 4 years until its time to rewrite the site....
Hopefully some of you have some experience or already have done a proper research to help me decide if it's worth the time to do something about it.
I am not interested in workarounds since if this is a serious issue I have found info about different ways to reduce the viewstate. (Although it requires me to understand the framework and code.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

some search engines only process the first few KBs of the page if the page size is large. As viewstate is a hidden input at the top of the form/page this can impact SEO as the actual content of the page may not get fully processed by the search engine if there is too much viewstate. Look into moving the viewstate to the bottom of the page.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MovingViewStateToTheBottomOfThePage.aspx

Comment: Granted, with the additional point that if your viewstate is this large on a public internet site you probably want to think about how to trim it down to save on bandwidth and make your app seem snappier.

Comment: Thanks.The KB issue does make sense for long pageviews.

Answer (score 3):

It can cause excessive page weight but this will not hurt your standing with the search engines.  ViewState is stored in a hidden input which are mainly ignored by search engines.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old but in ASP.Net every control including the page itself has a property called EnableViewState. All one has to do is turn it to false if they do not need a control to maintain state or for that matter the page itself